# Automating to run a SQL query on Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am automating the database count, database name, database creation date using powershell script for multiple SQL Servers using below query:

```
#load the assembly
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")
#read server names from a file
$servers = get-content "D:\dbcount\servers.txt"
$servers | $db = $server.Databases["master"]
$db.ExecuteWithResults("SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS db_count , 
name AS db_name , create_date AS db_creation_date FROM sys.databases WHERE 
[name] NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')")
```

But this query is giving below error:

Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.

Can anyone help me in this regards to resolve the error..

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this statement:

```
$servers | $db = $server.Databases["master"]
```

What happens here is `$servers` collection (an array of strings) is piped to assignment statement `$db = $server.Databases["master"]` - and it does not make any sense to Powershell's parsing rules, thus the error.

I'd hazard a guess you are trying to iterate through the `$servers` like so,

```
$servers | % {
    $server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server
    $server.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString = "data source = $_,..."
    $db = $server.Databases["master"]
    ...
}
```

What's more, the TSQL query seems peculiar too, as count of databases id duplicated on every row in addition to DB name and creation date.

Comment: Thanks Von, you are right, I want to run the same query on different servers which are in the list in D:\dbcount\servers.txt file. Yes count of databases is duplicating but it will work for me no issues. I want to know what should I write in data source line , if i give path D:\dbcount\servers.txt will it work?

Comment: The `data source` part is where one builds a connection string that points to whatever Sql Server instance you are working with. Exact details are various, so see [some samples](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/).

Comment: But in this case I guess , I will not be able to iterate same query for multiple servers using connection string, which I have kept in D:\dbcount\servers.txt